# R Incorrect Number of Dimensions Error from data.frame Assignment

Tags: r, glmmtmb

When running the code below I get the error:

> Error in data[, 4] : incorrect number of dimensions

Both *data[,4]* and *goals* have the same length (480) so I don't understand what the issue is. *Data* is a data.frame with 4 columns and *goals* is a length 480 vector.

```
library(glmmTMB)

simulate_games = function(data) {
  
  mod <- glmmTMB(goals ~ home + (1|attack) + (1|defence), poisson, data=data, REML=TRUE)
  goals = predict(mod,newdata = data, type = "response")
  
  
  data[,4] = goals #Error here
  res = comp_ranks(goals)[,2] #comp_ranks is a user defined function
  for (i in 1:1000) {
    data[,4] = rpois(480,goals)
    res = cbind(res,comp_ranks(data)[,2])
    
  }
  
  
  return(res)
  
}

long <- read.csv("https://www.math.ntnu.no/emner/TMA4315/2020h/eliteserie.csv", colClasses = c("factor","factor","factor","numeric"))

simulate_games(long)
```

Here is also the *comp_ranks* function although I don't think its whats causing the error.

```
comp_ranks = function(data) {
  
  goals = data[,4]
  goals = goals[!is.na(goals)]
  teams = unique(data[,1])
  teams_points = cbind.data.frame(0,teams)
  goals_scored = cbind.data.frame(0,teams)
  goals_conceded = cbind.data.frame(0,teams)
  
  for (i in 1:length(teams)) {
    
    
    tfs = data[,1] == teams[i]
    tfc = data[,2] == teams[i]
    goals_scored[i,1] = sum(na.omit(goals[tfs]))
    goals_conceded[i,1] = sum(na.omit(goals[tfc]))
    
  }
  
  for (i in seq(1,length(goals)-1,2)) {
    
    
    idx_1 = match(data[,1][i],teams)
    idx_2 = match(data[,1][i+1],teams)
    
  
    if (goals[i] - goals[i+1] > 0) {
      teams_points[idx_1,1] = teams_points[idx_1,1] + 3
    }
      
    else if (goals[i] - goals[i+1] < 0 ) {
      teams_points[idx_2,1] = teams_points[idx_2,1] + 3
    }
    else {
      
      
      teams_points[idx_1,1] = teams_points[idx_1,1] + 1
      teams_points[idx_2,1] = teams_points[idx_2,1] + 1
      
    }
    
    
}

  
  #Sort data.frame by ranks

  colnames(teams_points) = c("Points","Teams")
  teams_points = teams_points[with(teams_points, order(-Points)), ]
  diff = goals_scored[,1] - goals_conceded[,1]
  goals_diff = cbind.data.frame(diff,teams)
  teams_ranked = teams_points[,2]
  
  
  
    for (i in 1:length(teams_points)) {
      for (j in 1:length(teams_points)) {
        if(j != i) {
          if (teams_points[i,1] == teams_points[j,1]) {
            if (goals_diff[i,1] == goals_diff[j,1]) {
                if (goals_scored[i,1] < goals_scored[j,1] ) {
                  teams_ranked = replace(teams_ranked,c(i,j), teams_ranked[c(j,i)])
                  teams_points[,2] = teams_ranked
                  
                }
            else if(goals_diff[i,1] < goals_diff[j,1] ) {
              teams_ranked = replace(teams_ranked,c(i,j), teams_ranked[c(j,i)])
              teams_points[,2] = teams_ranked
                
            }
        }
        
      }
      
    }
          
      }
    }
      
  
  ranks = data.frame("Ranks" = c(1:16), "Teams" = teams_points[,2], "Points" = teams_points[,1])
  return(ranks)
    }
```

Comment: Please include all the necessary non-base packages required for your question to be reproducible. `glmmTMB`, `comp_ranks` are not base R function.

Comment: @RonakShah I appreciate the input, but the issue is that Im not allowed to write data[,4] at all inside the function without getting an error. If I instead write data[,4] = c(1:480) the result is the exact same. The comp_ranks is a long function and it doesen't seem like its directly relevant to the error Im getting.

Comment: Then remove it from the question since your error occurs before `comp_ranks` comes into picture. Btw, when I remove all the lines after  `data[,4] = goals` I don't get any error and it works without any error.